# Better alternatives to know whether a control is valid in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to know whether a control is valid or not in JavaScript. Is there a direct client side API available in Asp.Net which can tell me whether a control is valid or not?

Eg. If I have 2 validators attached to a textbox, I need a function that can tell me whether the textbox is valid or not. If even 1 validator is not valid then it should return false.

I can't seem to find a function that can give me this. Here is a little helper that I wrote which does the job but is inefficient:

```
function isControlValid(control) {
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        var validator = Page_Validators[i];
        var controlId = validator.controltovalidate;
        if ($(control).attr('id') == controlId && validator.isvalid == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Anybody has any better alternatives?

Comment: I'm curious. What is the length of Page_Validators? Running length * an equality comparison of an ID and a property shouldn't be that brutal unless there is an obscene number of these things loaded on to the page.

Comment: @Erik: That is true. But I was curious to know if any built in API is available or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work.

```
function isControlValid(control) {
    var validators = $(control).Validators;
    var isValid = true;
    Array.forEach(validtors, function(item) {
        isValid = isValid && (item.isvalid === true);
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is better than the one you proposed because the entire page validators is not iterated. Only the ones associated with the control is used for iteration. `$(control).Validators` is used to retrieve the validators associated with the control.

Comment: The code that I wrote already works. I need a better alternative. The code you wrote also basically does the same. It iterates all pages's validators.

Comment: Anthony, the code which I wrote basically iterated the validator associated to the specified control and not the entire page validators.

Comment: ahh ok. I overlooked that. I modified my code. I only needed to change it to $(control).Validators. Didn't know that was possible. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure whether it was the right way as I am not sure with jQuery. Will update my code.

Comment: Be aware that Array.forEach will only work in the latest browser versions. This script will not work in IE8 and below.

Comment: @grant valid point. But I think if we include Microsoft Ajax library (which gets injected by ScriptManager) it would introduce Array.forEach. Any if that is not the case we can go for jquery's foreach

Comment: (A) Hmm I'm actually surprised the code above seems to work as is, since the `Validators` collection is applied by ASP.net, and as such it is applied to the javascript element `control` and not to the jQuery element `$(control)`. For me the same code fails, but `control.Validators` works.

And (B) to shorten the run even further - you could break the `Array.forEach()` upon finding the first `!item.isvalid`, using the `return false;` statement: `if (!item.isvalid) { isValid = false; return false; }`

Comment: Sorry, to correct my previous comment's part (B) - the `return false;` will only break a jQuery's `.each()` loop. Since you obviously use jQuery - I recommend using it instead of `Array.forEach()` :)